# Amperage for the electrolysis of water?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, hydrogen, electricity

I am electrolysing water using several different potential catalysts for my eight grade science fair project. The electrolysis will be running at 2 to 2.5
volts over nickel electrodes, as I do not need a long term solution. How much amperage should I put on my DC power supply? Thanks and I would appreciate simplified answer compared to what you would normally give. Yes, I do understand ohms law.

Edit: I did some calculation and if I assume the resistance of the electrolyte is lets say 5 ohms, then we can assume a current of 0.5A at 2.5 volts. Is this correct?

Comment: Not exactly. To use Ohms law on an electrolysis cell, you have to subtract the cell voltage. Only when you increase the voltage above that level, a current starts to flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In electrochemistry, the rate of electrolysis depends on rate of charge entering the cell. Second most important point is that one can either control potential or current but *not both* during electrolysis i.e. you cannot have both values set. If you are fixing potential at 2.5 V, the value of current is not in your hand. I don't think Ohm's law remains valid *during* electrolysis in general.

So the main question one should ask is: What rate of electrolysis do I need? For example, you may want 200 mL of $\ce{O2}$ in 60 min. From here you calculate the charge *Q* needed to collect this volume of oxygen. Current is charge per unit time (3600 s) and this is your required current above the decomposition voltage of current. See second figure: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/electrolysis.html

See the sample calculation here: https://www.quora.com/What-amount-of-current-is-required-to-produce-0-224-cc-STP-of-O_2-at-anode-during-the-electrolysis-of-water